# jqueryUI destroy dialog without removing original element?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQueryUI to create a dialog, I want the dialog object to be destroyed when it's removed.

So I did something like this:

```
thisDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen:   true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        thisDialog.dialog("destroy");
    }
});
```

What I want to do is maintain the existence of the element that thisDialog is attached to, but simply destroy the jQueryUI `.dialog()` object that is attached to it, **not** change my DOM.

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ytWPV/1/

**Update:**
This may be a bug/issue with jQueryUI? If someone can show that, I'll accept that as an answer as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718640/how-to-recreate-jquery-dialog-after-destroy ?

Comment: That's not an answer to what I'm asking, .destory manintains the the dom manipulation and moves my div into the body container with all new settings.

Comment: Incognito is right. When you close the jQueryUI .dialog() it will automatically remove the element that it worked on. It would be nice to have a option that would prevent this. But Incognito's solution works nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish with "destroy" versus "close", but I will assume you have good reasons.

If you can successfully close your dialog (essentially setting the entire DIV that represents your dialog to the CSS equivalent of display:none) but want to go further and have the html more permanently removed from the DOM, I would add some logic to the close function that would use a selector (any selector will suffice) to find the top-most DIV for your dialog and then to manually set the .html() for that DIV to and empty string.  That will basically wipe out the internal HTML and leave you with only your original  that once acted as a dialog...

Comment: See, that removes the HTML inside the object. When I say object.destroy, I just want to destroy the javascript object { ... } in a way that doesn't change my DOM <div> ... </div>.

Comment: That should be the default behavior of the "destroy" you referenced.  It returns your DIV back to the original state, pre-init...

Comment: It should be, but when I destroy it removes the element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ytWPV/1/

Comment: User, turns out you are kinda right.  It does put the element back in the DOM more or less as it was before the element was transformed into the dialog.  The problem seems to be however, it does not return the element to the appropriate place in the DOM (in your case within your DIV decorated with the "hide" class).  If you inspect the DOM manually after calling destroy, you will see it is still around, just not where it was initially.  See this bug post as well: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4980

Comment: Accepted for pointing out the relevant bug. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try cloning the element if it doesn't change such as:

```
$("#win2").clone().attr("id","random").dialog({
    autoOpen:    true,
    height:     60,
    width:         50,
    modal:         true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        alert($(".hide").html())
        this.dialog("destroy");
    }
});
```

...which the original code came from your example.

Comment: Won't this end up inserting two elements into the DOM with the same `id`?

Comment: Good point. Although not ideal, I have changed it to include a different id.

Comment: Then again, the OP doesn't want the DOM changed. :/

Comment: I think this may be a "bug" report... Perhaps I should close the question?